# Ubuntu 12.04, Windows 2012 Active Directory Integration, Kerberos won't resolve service principals

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, windows-server-2012, kerberos

after having checked the whole internet literally, I hope that I might get help here.

I am trying to accomplish integration of ubuntu 12.04 servers into a Windows 2012 active directory with nfs and single sign on.

## setup:

- srv02 Windows server
- srv03 Ubuntu file server
- srv04 Ubuntu application server
- domain: lettrich.local
- realm: LETTRICH.LOCAL

## what works

- windows 2012 AD setup with dns ntp and dhcp
- ubuntu servers registert in ad with msktutil and getting

  1. kerberos tickets for users (eg. kinit Administrator@LETTRICH.LOCAL works)
  2. and machines ( kinit -k srv03$@LETTRICH.LOCAL works),
  3. uids and gids get resolved using identity management for UNIX on AD and sssd over gssapi.

## What does not work:

- mounting an NFS share on srv04 hosted on srv03.
- getting a kerberos ticket for service principals.

eg.

```
sudo kdestroy
sudo kinit -k
kinit: Client 'host/srv03.lettrich.local@LETTRICH.LOCAL' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials
```

krb5.keytab on srv03, analog for srv04.

```
sudo klist -ke
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  10 srv03$@LETTRICH.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac) 
  10 srv03$@LETTRICH.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  10 srv03$@LETTRICH.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  10 nfs/srv03.lettrich.local@LETTRICH.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac) 
  10 nfs/srv03.lettrich.local@LETTRICH.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  10 nfs/srv03.lettrich.local@LETTRICH.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  10 host/srv03.lettrich.local@LETTRICH.LOCAL (arcfour-hmac) 
  10 host/srv03.lettrich.local@LETTRICH.LOCAL (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
  10 host/srv03.lettrich.local@LETTRICH.LOCAL (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

nfs exports:

```
cat /etc/exports
/export               gss/krb5(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure,crossmnt,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
/export/users           gss/krb5(rw,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure,nohide,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
/export/groups           gss/krb5(rw,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure,nohide,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
/export/share           gss/krb5(rw,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure,nohide,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
/export/backup           gss/krb5(rw,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure,nohide,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
```

mounting on srv04

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 srv03:/export /mnt
```

gives me the error

```
srv04 rpc.gssd[754]: ERROR: No credentials found for connection to server srv03
```

Active directory has both srv03 and srv04 listed as domain computers with correct service principal names.(names changed accordingly)

```
service principal name = nfs/srv03.lettrich.local; host/srv03.lettrich.local
```

Where is my mistake? (and yeah, time is in sync ;-) )

Will provide further information if needed.

Thanks to all in advance who are willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit, that over time I forgot to answer and close this thread. Following these instructions along with creating the correct SSSDconfiguration resolved my issues:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1924660

Answer (score 1):

First, you should register straight and revert DNS record for new linux servers. Register this in windows domain.

Second, in Linux servers point DNS resolver to Windows, and modify /etc/hosts in linux for properly fields

Third, you must install Kerberos5 and winbind apps/modules/libraries

Fourth, configure /etc/krb5.conf with:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = YOUR.FULL.DOMAIN.WITH.UPPER.CHARS

[realms]
    YOUR.FULL.DOMAIN.WITH.UPPER.CHARS = {
            kdc = list of IPs windows domain servers
            admin_server = one ip for master domain server
    }

[domain_realm]
    your.full.comain.with.lover.chars = YOUR.FULL.DOMAIN.WITH.UPPER.CHARS

[logging]
#example logging
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/kadmin.log
    default = FILE:/var/log/kerberos/krb5lib.log
```

Fifth, configure /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]
workgroup = YOUR.SHORT.DOMAIN.WITH.UPPER.CASE
netbios name = YOUR.SERVER.NAME.WITH.UPPER.CASE.WITHOUT.DOMAIN
realm = YOUR.FULL.DOMAIN.WITH.UPPER.CHARS
security = ads
password server = windows.ip.server.what.allows.password.change
wins server = as.above.supports.wins.messages
wins proxy = no
kerberos method = system keytab
dedicated keytab file = /etc/krb5.keytab
server string = write what you want using %h as host name
dns proxy = no
idmap config * : backend = rid
idmap config * : range = 10000-20000
winbind use default domain = Yes
winbind enum users = Yes
winbind enum groups = Yes
winbind nested groups = Yes
winbind separator = +
winbind refresh tickets = yes
template shell = /bin/bash
template homedir = /home/%D/%U
preferred master = no
inherit acls = Yes
map acl inherit = Yes
acl group control
```

Sixsth, verify you are able to connect using temporarly any user:

```
wbinfo -t   #test only
net getdomainsid  #should print local and domain identifier
wbinfo -u   #domain user list, may take long time for many users
wbinfo -g   #domain group list
```

Seventh, create technical user account that password never expires and cannot be changed. Others leave default. Collect that user in separate AD directory :)

Eighth, generate keytab:

net ads keytab create -U your.technical.user@YOUR.FULL.DOMAIN.WITH.UPPER.CHARS

then check /etc/krb5.keytab exists

At now you can configure other services, specially using ntlm helper. You can test for connection using:

```
ntlm_auth --username UPPER.CASE.SHORTNAME.DOMAIN+your.technical.username
```

write password and you should see status:

```
NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)
```

At now you can configure PAM for authenticate many services, but I didn't do this. I succesfully use that config with apache2.2 ntlm authentication. I saw pam config for ssh and Xsession.

The main idea is, only winbind authenticates to Active Directory. All other services authenticates locally to winbind by any way. Winbind is part of samba. If you don't need samba, install only winbind, this installs some samba libraries.

Sometimes when you configure connection, wbinfo fails to connect. You must then wait for a moment, 5 or more minutes for domain info propagation.

Of course, time on all mashines should be in sync. Configure NTP for this.
I'm using debian, but ubuntu makes all similar to debian :) good luck.

Comment: I found some document that describes what I did: http://lugh.ch/kb-sso.html

Comment: Thanks for this very extensive answer, which I hope will help other admins with equal issues. I managed to get the problem fixed myself some time ago. I posted the link to the set of instructions that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the SPNs for the clients?

I have had good results using Samba to do this (**net ads join**).

Comment: hi I used msktinit, since samba (net ads join) added deprecated encryption types (des), which are no longer considered secure. however I got the same results with net ads join.